# Selenium chromedriver simply does not detect certain websites or their elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, frame

python script written to interact with a certain website through chromedriver can not find any elements or print page sources. the whole page is inside a frame inside a frame set. it seems switching to the frame is the advice people give in this situation. I am unable to find the frame either with a tag name or XPath

general HTML of the website

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
           <frameset>
                    <frame src="ebrokerlogin.html">
                          <html>
                               rest of website !!!!!!!!!      
                          /html>
                     </frame>
           </frameset>
</html>
```

once the page opens these lines run

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("frame"))
print(driver.page_source)
```

the exception I receive is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"frame"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

How can I switch to the frame on the website? why does my method not work?

[evidence of tag name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIMzG.png)

ps: if I comment out the driver.switch_to, the page source that prints out is from the previous website, not this one.

update: evidence of XPath not working either
[evidence of xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Kfs.png)

Comment: what happens when you try to locate the element by xpath? have you tried waiting for the page to load?

Comment: same ill add more evidence showing that and yes both implicity and with time.sleep(10)

Comment: if driver.page_source prints out the html of a different website before you switch to the frame, you might not have switched pages at all. try printing the current url before you switch the frame. if that's wrong, then make sure you're switching urls before you try to switch to the frame

Comment: jd rudie. you were correct thank you

Answer (score 0):

selenium got this website by clicking on a link. it seemed to continue believing it was on the previous website